# What test should I run to show if there is a correlation between two binary variables?

Tags: correlation, binary-data, association-rules

I have two variable religion and healthy. The answers are coded as yes or no. I want to see if health is related to religion.

Answer (score 3):

There is a number of correlation measures for binary data including [$\phi$ coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient) and [Cohen's $\kappa$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen's_kappa) among the commonly used ones. Alexander et al. (1985) after conducting a simulation study concluded that $\phi$ and $\kappa$ are not the most efficient ones with the [odds ratio](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183474/odds-made-simple) based coefficient by Chambers being the best in their study. Below you can see a table summarizing different measures provided in this paper. Modern methods as tetrachoric correlation are implemented in different software, like R's [psych library](http://www.personality-project.org/r/html/tetrachor.html).

[image]

Since a number of different measures exist, you should probably start with doing a review of their pros and cons for your particular purpose.

As *@Glen_b* noticed, you seem mention testing the difference about those two binary variables. If it is so, you may be rather interested in methods such as [$\chi^2$ test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson's_chi-squared_test), [binomial test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test), or [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) (cf. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163034/bayesian-logit-model-intuitive-explanation/163039#163039)) and [odds ratios](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34636/interpretation-of-simple-predictions-to-odds-ratios-in-logistic-regression/34638#34638), for learning more about those methods see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177816/logistic-regression-vs-chi-square-in-a-2x2-and-ix2-single-factor-binary-respo) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8052/2x2-chi-square-test-vs-binomial-proportion-statistic).

---

Alexander, R. A., Alliger, G. M., Carson, K. P., & Barrett, G. V. (1985). The empirical performance of measures of association in the 2× 2 table. *Educational and psychological measurement, 45(1)*, 79-87.

David Kirk (1973) On the numerical approximation of the bivariate normal (tetrachoric) correlation coefficient. *Psychometrika, 38*, 259-268.

Comment: +1 Since the question seems to be about testing rather than measuring (see the title), it might be worth mentioning *testing*.